# How can sperm become embryos without ovum or eggs?

Tags: reproduction

How could I make sperm become an embryo or turn sperm into ova so the embryo is grown inside the sperm and then grows in size until hatching in water like external fertilization and get paternal mitochondria dna?

[image]

Comment: It cannot. Spermatozoids are very highly specialized cells, which lack lots of machinery. For example, spermatozoids do not have mitochondria. (And the question is unclear. If they don't have eggs, what is the egg bank for? Does it sit empty?)

Comment: *"How could sperm become an embryo without an egg of an woman and strictly reproduce by androgenesis?"* I'm afraid that that is not what is actually meant by the word [androgenesis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgenesis&ved=2ahUKEwiC-qfL-cD5AhUjkFwKHUB9BEQQFnoECCkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw24Dwf5iK1us7C7A8dxhF2f) .. an egg cell is used, it simply doesn't use any of the maternal nuclear DNA in developing the new organism.

Comment: In what kind of organism?

Comment: Why not just skip to a species with asexual reproduction?

Comment: No, It would by definition they would then not be spermatozoa if they could.

Comment: You have a definition problem. What then makes the male's gamete cells meet the definition of sperm cell? What makes that sex fit the definition of male and the other sex as female? A sperm cell is a gamete with reduced information and equipment, missing the wherewith-all to become an embryo without a host egg cell. You might by definition have a hermaphrodite species. You definitely have reduced reproductive dimorphism. You can have a species as you described but the difficult part is defining how they have a male-female gamete roll.

Comment: Females have the larger gamete the males of my species have sperm identical to human sperm and swims like sperm but if the sperms can't find an egg it develops into an clone embryo of the male similarly to androgenesis

Comment: *"if the sperms can't find an egg it develops into an clone embryo of the male **similarly to androgenesis**"* accept that that is not *'similar to'* androgenises, not even close, because that is not how androgenises works, androgenises involves a host egg cell, did you not read the link I already provided?

Comment: The sperm are effective intracellular parasites of rectal enterocytes.  They acquire cytoplasm, become metastatic, and colonize the liver.  The strongest embryos seize the most blood supply with VEGF-like growth factors.  They develop dispersal mutations (a mature nervous system, wings, very sharp teeth...) and burrow through the abdominal wall, usually killing the host.  They feed after the manner of vampire bats until they are large enough to pupate, mimicking human newborns to act as brood parasites.

Answer (score 2):

**Could sperm become an embryo without an egg?**

No not really.

As Alex points out in your comments sperm lack a lot of the necessery machinery, and by the time you've added that machinery you're basically going to have an egg cell.

Howsoever.

If what you're after is just an all male species there is a path that can allow that.

[Kleptogenisis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klepton&ved=2ahUKEwjRpaeg7sD5AhXKN8AKHVUgANoQFnoECBcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3H4D7PzylSg71qC8JfqIcF)

An all male species might reproduce by hijacking the necessery machinery in a closely related species egg cells and discarding the additional genetic material.

This means they mate with members of this other species and the female carries the offspring to term but contributes no genetic material other than the mitochondrial DNA .. so will give birth to a member of a different species, the fathers, rather than her own.

Such an all male species are most likely all clones of their fathers but there are other mechanisms that might be employed to shuffle the father's genes a little without using any of the mothers.

..

*A potential path to such an all male species would be the more standard form of [androgenisis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgenesis&ved=2ahUKEwiC-qfL-cD5AhUjkFwKHUB9BEQQFnoECCkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw24Dwf5iK1us7C7A8dxhF2f) arising in a single species that led to the 'extinction' of all females of that species forcing the remaining male only species to then use females of another closely related species to reproduce.*

..

*"the female carries the offspring to term"*

Well, unless you use a couple of species that do it like a seahorse of course.

..

> If you want to explore this idea with further questions you should check out other questions that have already been asked on this subject first to avoid duplication.

Answer (score -1):

Have a unisexual species that reproduces by raping unwilling hosts. Their reproductive material isn't haploid like human sperm but it still moves around searching for the perfect place to emplant and so serves most of the same functions as regular sperm.

It could go further and not actually emplant, instead the injected cells consume the host as they grow.